"Image as Planes/Mesh Plane" is gone from "Import" tab in Blender 4.2. How to get it back?
As you may have noticed, Blender 4.2, along with all its new features, has updated many small details that, at first glance, didn’t seem necessary. One of these updates involved the "Images as Planes" section. On one hand, it has been renamed to "Mesh Plane," but on the other hand, it has completely disappeared from the File menu.
This change has disrupted my muscle memory and the macros assigned to my mouse. I was wondering if there is a way to restore this section to the location shown in the screenshot I’ve provided? Thank you! =)

it's under ShiftA > Image > Mesh Plane

I know this is the way, but i really miss the second option due too it being available through shortcut
